Show error page when Capacitor server URL is not available
In an Ionic project with Capacitor, I want to load the project from a URL in the webview by using the url variable in the capacitor.config.ts file:
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  ...
  webDir: 'www',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    iosScheme: 'https',
    cleartext: true,
    url: 'http://192.168.1.54:8081'
  },
  ...
}

I've been able to load the URL, but if there's no connection a blank page will appear when opening the app.
How can I show an error page in that case to avoid showing a blank screen?
I tried several solutions but none worked. The error page should be in the local project, not in the server, but if I build the app with a URL server in the config all the local code is ignored when the webview is loaded, so I can't access the error page. Also I haven't found any solution to change the config URL at runtime.

There is an errorPath configuration option you can use to specify the path to a local html page to display in case of errors:
{
  "server": {
    "errorPath": "..."
  }
}

But keep in mind that the url configuration option is not intended for use in production. I recommend using live updates instead. They offer the same advantages (immediate delivery of updates) but have significantly fewer disadvantages (offline support, ...).
